# How can I show the old eth0 names and also rename network interfaces in debian 9 stretch?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I would like to do 2 things:

1) Revert back the interfaces to the old classic name: eth0 instead of ens33.

2) Rename the interfaces in the way I want so that for example I can call interface eth0 as wan0 or assign eth1, eth2 and so on the mac address I want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming that you have just installed your debian 9 stretch.

**1) For reverting back the old names for the interfaces do:**

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"`

then launch a **grub-mkconfig** for apply the changes inside the bootloader

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You need a **reboot** after that.

---

**2) For renaming the interfaces use:**

- For just a temporary modification take a look at the @xhienne answer.
- For a permanent modification:

Start by creating / editing the **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** file.

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

And insert inside lines like:

```
# interface with MAC address "00:0c:30:50:48:a1" will be assigned "eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:30:50:48:a1", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# interface with MAC address "00:0c:30:50:48:ab" will be assigned "eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:30:50:48:ab", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

If you want to assign for example a name like wan0 to eth0 you can use given my example:

```
# interface with MAC address "00:0c:30:50:48:a1" will be assigned "eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:30:50:48:a1", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="wan0"
```

After the next **reboot** or using **service networking restart** you should see the changes applied.

---

**EXTRA:** Remember that after all this modifications you have to edit your **/etc/network/interfaces** file replacing the old interfaces names with the new ones!

---

**EXTRA:** If you want to know what MAC address your interfaces have, just do a

```
ip addr show
```

and look under the **link/** section.

Comment: Where can is this info found in the official Linux documentation?

Comment: For debian this can be found here https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames and also that biosdevname=0 is not required for debian but only for old RedHat and some other distributions.

Answer (score 7):

For question 1) see [user3450548's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396383/203203). For question 2) you can give any name you want to an interface with `iproute2`:

```
ip link set ens33 down           # Else you will get "Device or resource busy"
ip link set ens33 name eth0
```

Comment: Oh nice, however this isn't just a temporary change until the next reboot ?

Comment: Yes. Of course you can add this in a startup script, but your answer is better if you want something permanent. I didn't notice you were answering your own question (you may accept it then) and added this if you (or anyone else) would like a temporary name change for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice addon, I will point the temporary solution to your answer aswell :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a very easy way by changing only `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
rename enp3s0=wan0
```

Then

```
service networking restart
```

to restart the networking service.

Comment: That looks really good. Because I struggled to find the offical documentation before: It is here https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html , and `rename` is  documented.

Comment: Using the keyword `rename` works only in the original `ifupdown` package; the replacement package `ifupdown2` doesn't knows this keyword and restarting the service will fail with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Create below file if not there

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

add below line

```
# interface with MAC address "00:0c:30:50:48:a1" will be assigned "eth0"
# KERNEL=="enp3s0" is debians current interface name
# NAME="eth0" is a new ethernet interface name
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:30:50:48:a1", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="enp3s0", NAME="eth0"
```

Answer (score 1):

These days [systemd.link - Network device configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) offers a comfortable method to rename interfaces persistently.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have mixed it up with /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Answer (score 0):

There are simple steps to follow.

1. Open Terminal and type

   ```shell
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Comment the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` as per shown in the below screenshot.

   [image]

   Add new line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"`

   Press `X` then `y` for save and exit.
3. Type

   ```shell
   grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub. cfg
   ```
4. reboot the machine. Done!