# Debian 9; setting network devices for an www server

Tags: debian, routing, wlan

I'm trying to set up apache2 server on Debian 9. I'm using an laptop with Ralink network-card, witch was able to use eth0, at Debian 8, with looks more familiar for me. Since I update my system to 9 my network interface has changed and looks something like this:

```
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp37s0   1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo       65536      612      0      0 0           612      0      0      0 LRU
wlo1      1500    36736      0      1 0         20492      0      0      0 BMRU
```

and  in the `/etc/interfaces.d/setup` file it's defined like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

What is the `enp37s0`? And why am I connected to the router with wlo1, not eth0?

My routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.63.16.1      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.63.16.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
```

Is that a proper configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do see [Chapter 2. What's new in Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.html) from the [Release Notes for Debian 9 (stretch), 64-bit PC](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/index.en.html)

> 2.2.9. New method for naming network interfaces
>
> The installer and newly installed systems will use a new standard
>   naming scheme for network interfaces instead of eth0, eth1, etc. The
>   old naming method suffered from enumeration race conditions that made
>   it possible for interface names to change unexpectedly and is
>   incompatible with mounting the root filesystem read-only. The new
>   enumeration method relies on more sources of information, to produce a
>   more repeatable outcome. It uses the firmware/BIOS provided index
>   numbers and then tries PCI card slot numbers, producing names like
>   ens0 or enp1s1 (ethernet) or wlp3s0 (wlan). USB devices, which can be
>   added to the system at any time, will have names based upon their
>   ethernet MAC addresses.
>
> This change does not apply to upgrades of jessie systems; the naming
>   will continue to be enforced by
>   /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. For more information, see
>   /usr/share/doc/udev/README.Debian.gz or the upstream documentation.

see also [How can I show the old eth0 names and also rename network interfaces in debian 9 stretch?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396382/how-can-i-show-the-old-eth0-names-and-also-rename-network-interfaces-in-debian-9)

I would advise you to take a bit of time to familiarize yourself with Debian 9 before upgrading Debian 8 to Debian 9 systems, and/or following recent documentation/tutorials as the changes under the hood are significant.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9 moved to newer-style network interface naming in new installations. If you updated from Debian 8 to 9, someone or something may have deliberately deleted the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file which would have maintained the old names.

- `enp37s0` is a wired (`en`) network device whose PCI bus ID in `lspci` output is 25:00.0 (37 in decimal = 25 in hex) and which is not integrated to the motherboard (as far as the firmware/BIOS information indicates). It has just a single port. A dual-port NIC might have names like `enp37s0f0` and `enp37s0f1` corresponding to PCI IDs 25:00.0 and 25:00.1.
- `wlo1` is a wireless (`wl`) network device that is integrated onboard (`o`) and is the first such one (`1`) as indicated by the firmware/BIOS information.

Directory `/etc/interfaces.d/` should not be there, do you mean `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`?

You should replace any references to `eth0` in your network configuration with `enp37s0`. Other than the new name, the network interface should then behave just the same as before.