# How can I rename ZeroTier interfaces in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, network-interface

It seems that under a ZeroTier installation is not possible to use the classical method described in [How can I show the old eth0 names and also rename network interfaces in debian 9 stretch?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396382/how-can-i-show-the-old-eth0-names-and-also-rename-network-interfaces-in-debian-9/396383#396383)

How is it possible to rename the zerotier interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done depending if you want a renaming temporary or persistant.

## Temporary

```
/sbin/ip link set zt50a5b down
/sbin/ip link set zt50a5b name myzt0
/sbin/ip link set myzt0 up
```

## Persistent

Create a file called **devicemap** in `/var/lib/zerotier-one/`

```
nano /var/lib/zerotier-one/devicemap
```

then

fill it with lines in the format

```
network_id=interface_name
```

eg:

```
32af43...45=mytz0
14b45e...79=mytz1
```

save it and reboot

Comment: The "temporary" method is the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396392/70524 from the other question

Comment: ad "reboot") `systemctl restart zerotier-cli` should be sufficient.